# Calculating shortest paths with data extracted from a database

Tags: java, web-services

So I need to create a web service which will communicate with my Android 
application. In my android app the client choose two point start and 
arrival this two point will be send to my web service to find the bus 
that has the shortest path between them. I have a problem with the web 
service side.

I tried to use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path between 
two points. To test the Dijkstra algorithm I must extract data from a 
MySQL database and not put it right into my algorithm. I don't know 
how can I do it though.

In my database I have two table that contains the bus route (bus num), 
code (station id), pt_arret (station name). There's another table which 
contains location code (id station), latitude and longitude, and 
distance (is the distance between a station and the station which 
precedes.

Comment: Please could you take the time to format, capitalize and punctuate your question properly. Thanks.

Comment: (im sorry for the mistacke of spelling because i don't speak english very fluently)

Answer (score 0):

You've got to create a structure that will let you use Dijkstra's algorithm.  To do that, you must read *all* the relavant data from the database.  The transition from relational data to object oriented is always awkward.

Ideally you want to use a single, simple SQL select per table to get the data.  Optimization is tricky.  A single select statement can grab a million rows almost as fast as it can grab one row; one select will get a million rows faster than 10 selects will grab 10 rows (in my experience).  But grabbing too many uneeded rows might take too long if your DB connection is slow (has a narrow bandwidth).

Use Maps (TreeMap or HashMap) to keep track of what you read, so you can find "station" objects that have already been read and placed in your structure and add connections to them.

Once you have your data structure set up in memory, try to keep it around as long as possible to limit delays from rereading the database.

Keep an eye on your memory and timings.  You are in danger of running too slow for your users or running low on memory.  You need to pay attention to performance (which does not seem to be a common need, these days).  I've made some suggestions, but I can't really know what will happen with your hardware and data.  (For instance, reading the DB may not be as slow as I suspect.)

Hope this helps.  If you have not done anything like this before, you've got a lot of work and learning ahead of you.  I worked on a major program like this (but it also *wrote* to the DB), and I felt like I was swimming upstream all the way.

**Addition:**

What you want in memory is a set of stations (Station class objects) and routes (Route class objects).  Each station would have all the data you need to describe one stations including locations.  Critically, it would also need an ID.  The stations should go in a TreeMap using the ID as key.  (This is my predjudice, many people would use a HashMap.)

Each route will have references to the two stations it links, a distance or travel time, and any other needed information.

Each *station* will *also* contain a list of routes that reference it.  I'd recommend a LinkedList for flexibility.  (In this case, ArrayList is apt to waste a lot of space with unused array elements.)  You will want to read the stations from the db, then read route info.  As you read each route's info, create the Route object, locate the two stations, add references to them to the Route, then add the Route to both stations' route lists.

Now for each station you can spot all the routes leaving it, and then spot all the stations you can get to with one bus trip.  From those stations, you can work your way on, all through your network.  This structure really is a "sparse array", if you want to think of it that way.

Applying Dijkstra's algorithm--or any other algorithm--is quite straightforward.  You'll want various flags on the stations and routes (fields in the Station and Route classes) to track which nodes (stations) and connections (routes) you've already used for various purposes.  It might help to draw the map (start with a small one!) on a sheet of paper to track what your code is doing.  My experience has been that it takes very little code to do all this, but it takes a lot of careful thought.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I want to know:   to create this ws  what are the classes and functions that I need.?? because it is  my first ws,  and I do not know how to analyze this problem.

Comment: @olfa: Which area do you need help with?  I don't know web services and Android well enough to help you.  I could be a bit more specific about SQL, Java, and implementing Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: there is someone who advised me to do it like that:

Comment: @olfa: Sorry, but I do not understand you.

Comment: thres is some one that advised me to do it like that :To use Dijkstra's algorithm you need prepare a distance matrix. It's a two-dimensional array of distances between all stations.
Preffered solution is:
1. load both tables into memory as POCO data objects.
2. calculate distance matrix (if you can - create a sparce matrix to avoid big memory usage).
3. call Dijkstra's algorithm.... so where should extract the data from mysql (in wich class)? i'm sorry but i need help :(

Comment: @olfa:  Sound advice.  I've added my interpretation of it to my answer.  Should get you a bit further along.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice :) I'll try to translate it into code, but please if you know a tutorial that can help me do not hésitate to send me the url , because i'm beginner and i dont know if i can  build it from scratch. anyway I'll try and thank you again :)

Comment: @olfa:  Don't really know any tutorials.  For an example, you might look at this:  (http://www.binpress.com/app/roadgraph/316).  It's a commercial site but you can download "RoadGraph" code free for your own use.  It's __way__ more complicated than anything you need, but with some effort you can find the nodes and see how they're linked.

Comment: thank you very much for your help :) I hope that I find a solution as soon as possible because I lost a lot of time in research  and the report after 11 day :( :(....thank you again :)